# calling an instance method from instance's creation callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Was looking in SO for a solution, but couldn't find one.

```
let instance = new Obj(arguments, function() {
   instance.instanceMethod(function() {
      console.log('status');
   })
})
```

I'm trying to call a method of an instance from a callback in the instance creation. How can I properly implement this logic? The above doesn't work and node reports "instance" as undefined. I tried adding "bind(this)" to the end of the outer callback function, but that didn't work either.

Comment: `instance` or `instace` ?

Comment: How are you trying to call the callback? *instance* is not assigned a value until the right hand side is fully evaluated.

Comment: Is `Obj` your own class or a third-party class? If it is your own, how is it implemented? You may be able to use `this` to refer to `instance` in this case if the `Obj` constructor is implemented that way.

Comment: This will only work if the callback is executed asynchronously, or if the callback gets the object as a parameter. Otherwise `instance` won't yet be defined.

Comment: Pass a reference to the new object as an argument to the callback, or call the callback via `call()` to set `this` to the new object. (Of course, both options assume you can modify the `Obj()` function.)

Comment: You will have to show us the `Obj` function for us to advise further.  Until we see that code, all we do is offer guesses.   And, questions on stack overflow that require guessing to try to guess an answer are not good questions.  Please fix your question by adding the code for `Obj()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Obj(args, cb){
    setTimeout(cb, 0);    
}
Obj.prototype.instanceMethod = function(cb){cb();};

let instance = new Obj([1,2,3], function() {
   instance.instanceMethod(function() {
      console.log('status');
   })
});
```

use a setTimeout to call the function that use the instance `async`. so the instance will be valued first then the function call.